# how do I output this in ASP.NET MVC using Razor Engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm very new to the MVC platform and I was wondering how can I out put the following on to the page:

```
data: [
        { Status: '@model.status', From: '@model.from', To: '@model.to' },
        { Status: '@model.status', From: '@model.from', To: '@model.to' }
       ]
```

I have a for loop that creates multiple of rows of the `{Status: ..... To:}` but I can't get the text in the middle of all the `@model.`s

How do I do this? I was using the `@:` before all the text and also the  but it doesn't like those either.

Comment: Are you trying to output JSON?

Comment: @R0MANARMY no, its for a plugin that clones the inputs on the screen and populates them with the data above.

Comment: Try adding parentheses, something like `'@(model.status)'`.  I ran into a similar problem, but was using RazorEngine, I think it's a little bit behind what's built into ASP.NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found out that Razor is actually really smart. What I ended up doing was the following:

```
@: { Status: '@Model.Monday[i].Status', From: '@Model.Monday[i].From', To: '@Model.Monday[i].To' },
```

inside a for loop (because of the comma at the end.) Thanks for all the comments and suggestions.

Comment: your only issue was you were using `@model` instead of `@Model`

Comment: it's still recommended to put it inside parenthesis. `@(Model.Monday[i].Status)`

Comment: @wired_in No, when I typed it here I made that mistake, the actual mistake was not trusting Razor and Putting `@:` and `<text>` everywhere in the middle of the `@Model`
I will actually use the parenthesis as I can totally see the benefit.

Comment: @hjavaher In your sample code in your question, you didn't include `@:` anywhere. The only issue with that code was the `@model` instead of `@Model`

Comment: I've been using Razor for 15 months. I thought I knew this cold. But your angle is brilliant and I had the privilege of learning something new.

Comment: @DaveA I assure you it was: 1) the Lazy in me and 2) Pure luck in my part 3) absolutely no brilliance lol

Comment: Any particular reason you're using a `for` loop instead of `foreach`?

Comment: @R0MANARMY yes, because I want to be able to tell if I have reached the last element. Honestly I was too lazy to figure out how to do that with a foreach.

Comment: You probably can't tell when you've reached the last element.  I'm guessing it's because you don't want to append the `,` at the end of the last element.  In that case you could just treat the first element differently by not starting it with a `,`.  But fair enough, `for` loop will work just as well.

Comment: @R0MANARMY Precisely. I did see a clever way of detecting the last element of a foreach somewhere once but I couldn't find it and didn't want to spend much time looking for it.